# Toggle class on and off in jquery with button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to javascript but I'm having a hard time toggle this class on and off.

https://jsfiddle.net/spadez/o2s0hmtv/2/

```
$( "#togglebtn" ).click(function() {
  $(.mynav).toggleClass( "modal" );
});
```

Based on tutorials this should work, but the button doesn't seem to do anything. Can anyone show me where I went wrong please?

Comment: Missing quotes in `$(.mynav)`

Comment: Missing quotes - https://jsfiddle.net/o2s0hmtv/3/

Comment: Why downvotes on all the answers?

Comment: @Druzion probably because the question is off-topic, as being a typo, and there is no need for an answer, let alone three. The question will likely evaporate at some point, so nothing will be lost in the end. Typos questions are only any use if anyone else has the exact same typo.

Comment: Since its a minor typo, it may not be useful to have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$( "#togglebtn" ).click(function() {
$(".mynav").toggleClass( "modal" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its just typo. Jquery selectors should be enclosed in **'**(single quotes) or **"**(double quotes) .

https://jsfiddle.net/o2s0hmtv/4/

```
$( "#togglebtn" ).click(function() {
  $('.mynav').toggleClass( "modal" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes around selectors (`.mynav`) here.  Like this:

```
$( "#togglebtn" ).click(function() {
  $('.mynav').toggleClass("modal");
});
```